# Javascript promise, all the .then execute at the same time

Tags: javascript, promise

At the moment all the console.log following the .then, execute at the same time.
I want every .then to wait for the previous one, how can I do it?

```
function doIt(sentence) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(console.log(sentence))
        }, 2000)
    })
}

doIt('Place order')
    .then(() => setTimeout(() => { console.log('Cut the fruit') }, 2000))
    .then(() => setTimeout(() => { console.log('Add water and ice') }, 2000))
    .then(() => setTimeout(() => { console.log('Start the machine') }, 2000))
    .then(() => setTimeout(() => { console.log('Select topping') }, 2000))
    .then(() => setTimeout(() => { console.log('Serve the ice cream') }, 2000))
```

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so there is nothing to wait for.

Comment: `() => setTimeout(() => { console.log('Cut the fruit') }, 2000)` -> `() => doIt('Cut the fruit')` repeat the same for all of them. Although, that's only useful in this particular case. In most of the regular cases, you wouldn't need to do anything, as you shouldn't be using `setTimeout`. Most code should work "out of the box".

Comment: @VLAZ 'Most code should work "out of the box"'..but what if you do want it to have a delay between one then to other?

Comment: @Reyno so in then only react to promise?

Comment: @LilachBochov then you'd define a promise with delay like you have. Yet, that's not going to be needed the majority of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a promise chain.

```js
function doIt(sentence) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log(sentence)), 2000);
  });
}

doIt("Place order")
  .then(() => doIt("Cut the fruit"))
  .then(() => doIt("Add water and ice"))
  .then(() => doIt("Start the machine"))
  .then(() => doIt("Select topping"))
  .then(() => doIt("Serve the ice cream"));
```